# how to solve, htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The image shows the output after foreach then I displayed

```php
var_dump($myVariable)
```

but if I print the variable it gives the error

[image]

Comment: that's not an error, it's your variable dumped from [var_dump](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to echo out variables in the HTML (Blade view) use the `{{ }}` syntax

For example inside the foreach

```php
{{ $myVariable }}
```

But this would still show the variable (object) in a JSON (non human readable) format

You may want to show specific attributes from the variable

```php
{{ $myVariable->body_text }}
```

This will show the message text

Hope this helps

Comment: Why is it impossible to access the models, eg $myVariable->user->name

Comment: @OnassisKenan because you have an array of `stdClass` objects, not model instances ... did you use Query Builder instead of an Eloquent Model to do the query?

Comment: Yes, i used Query builder. I've solved the issue though.